# How can I add a network location with a space in the name to Windows Credential Manager?

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, credentials

My company has a backup server that has a space in its name ("Foo Bar").

I am trying to add the login credentials for this server to Windows Credential Manager, but I receive a canned error response (I am assuming this is due to the space. No space, no error):

```
Windows cannot save this information. Make sure the information is correct
and that all required fields are completed. 

Error code: 0x80070057. 
Error message: The parameter is incorrect
```

I have tried the following:

- Its network IP address (credential manager doesn't seem to ID an IP and server name as the same?)
- `\\Foo Bar\foobar`
- `"\\Foo Bar\foobar"` (same 0x80070057 error)
- `\\Foo%20Bar\foobar` (does not link to the server)
- `\\FooBar\foobar` (doesn't ID)
- `\\Foo-Bar\foobar` (doesn't ID)
- `"Foo Bar"` (same 0x80070057 error)

Unfortunately, I do not have permission to undertake the simplest solution (properly naming the server!).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have permission to give the server a proper name?  There may be two ways to do that.  #1: Adjust the server's name, on the server.  #2: Give the server another name.  Adjust name resolution.  (a.k.a., try adding a DNS entry, possibly as CNAME, or try modifying a hosts file.)

Comment: I understand you've tried several different host names.  But besides showing us those host names you tried, can you tell us just what you're doing?  I'm suspecting using a command line: can you show an entire example of a tried command line?

Answer (score 0):

If you can successfully connect to the share via `Net Use` I believe you can use the `/savecred` option to save those credentials into the WCM.

You will probably have to enclose the server/share name in quotes to prevent confusion by the space.  IE: `Net Use K: "\\Server Name\ShareName"`

> For the net use command to save the credentials in Credential Manager, use the /savecred switch. When you use the /savecred switch, any credentials that you are prompted for when you use the net use command are saved as a key.

Info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287536) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx).

Comment: Since the domain name is the server name, I'm having trouble using Net Use to connect; when prompted for the user name, using any of foo bar\user, "foo bar"\user, user@foo bar, "foo bar\user" throws an invalid user name response.

Comment: Aha, I was able to bypass the space in the domain by using %domain%\user

Comment: After successfully connecting via net use with the /savecred switch, I'm not seeing the credentials in WCM :\

Comment: @hztetra - Crappy.  (Un)Fortunately I've never actually had to do this in practice.. :)  Maybe try both "/Savecred" and "/Persistent:Yes"?  I doubt it'll help, but should be an easy test. :)

Comment: Also adding Persistent:Yes does not load the credentials into WCM either! I'm feeling defeated, heh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ^ to escape certain characters in Windows as well. Not sure if it will work but try \Foo^ Bar\foobar

Comment: Using a carrot did not work unfortunately :(

Comment: "The ampersand (&), pipe (|), and parentheses ( ) are special characters that must be preceded by the escape character (^) or quotation marks when you pass them as arguments."  Unfortunately those are the only characters you can escape in a Windows command-prompt.